# Why does LLDB print wrong values when debugging?

Tags: debugging, gdb, lldb

I'm trying to debugging some code but the value given by the debugger has nothing to do with the current one.

I have another laptop with Linux where gdb is installed and I got everything ok. The problem comes when I use LLDB on my MacBook.

The code is really simple, I just assign to my variable called v1 the value 12 and that's all. The problem doesn't come from the code.

When I execute the code step by step in LLDB and print the value of v1 before assigning I got 0 and after assigning I have '\f'.

For compiling I tried both gcc and clang with the option -g.

Comment: It might help to show the exact problem if you show your test program.  You mentioned that it is simple - is it simple enough to include in the question?  Also, how are you compiling it on macOS?  With clang or gcc?  With optimization (-O)?

Answer (score 0):

> When I execute the code step by step in LLDB and print the value of v1 before assigning I got 0 and after assigning I have '\f'.

Assuming `v1` is a stack variable, the value it contains *before* the assignment is undefined.

The value you print after: `\f` *is* `12`.

Why LLDB prints this value as a character and not as an integer is impossible to tell without seeing the source. Possibly because you declared it as a `char`.

Comment: I declared it as int8_t v1 = 12;

Comment: @EliasEl `int8_t` is often just an alias for `signed char`.